# Azure Active directory authentication with PCL Xamarin forms

Tags: authentication, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

Iam trying to create a cress platform mobile app using Xamarin forms. I am using an azure mobile service and have to authenticate to the Azure active directory. I have previously done this with Xamarin.Android. But I am not sure how to do this with PCL. I ahve already created a Mobile service and Active directory on Azure portal.

If anyone can guide me on how to go forward with this or provide me with any example it would be very helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ADAL v3.x preview does not yet support Xamarin.Forms. We are looking into it, but for the time being the preview available today needs iOS/Android/Win specific projects.

Answer (score 1):

There is ADAL support for PCL to authenticate to AAD:
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/30/adal-net-v3-preview-pcl-xamarin-support/